# Working with if else statements

Tags: java

Hi im trying to output a line when the user inputs a certain number. However the same line keeps appearing even thou i input another number. What am i doing wrong?

```
public class apples{
     public static void main(String args[]){
         int input1=1;
         int input2=2;
         int input3=3;
         int input4=4;
         System.out.println("Welcome to MK Supermarket");
         System.out.println("Four items are available for sale:");
         System.out.println("1.Flour 2.Crix 3.Juice 4.Cereal");
          Scanner sales = new Scanner (System.in);
         System.out.println("Press 1 for Flour, Press 2 for Crix, Press 3 for Juice, Press 4 for Cereal");

         int itemSelect=sales.nextInt();

         if(input1==1){
             System.out.println("You chose Flour");
             int price1=30;
         }
         else if(input2==2){
             System.out.println("You chose Crix");
             int price2=10;
         }
         else if(input3==3){
             System.out.println("You chose Juice");
             int price3=15;
         }
         else if(input4==4){
             System.out.println("You chose Cereal");
             int price4=25;
         }
         else{
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
         }

    }

}
```

This is the code i've written so far.
And this is the result:

```
Welcome to MK Supermarket
Four items are available for sale:
1.Flour 2.Crix 3.Juice 4.Cereal
Press 1 for Flour, Press 2 for Crix, Press 3 for Juice, Press 4 for Cereal
2
You chose Flour
```

Comment: In your code, `input1` will always be `1`. What else would you expect? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @user2812509 after you have write your codes, you have to go through on it. It just a minor mistake

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Delete all your `inputx` variables - they are useless.

Step 2: Change all your tests to:

```
if (itemSelect == 1)
```

etc. You need to test what is entered (not something else).

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything with the user input that you save into itemSelect.

Your first if statement compares input1, which you hardcoded to 1, with 1. this will always return true. And result in skipping the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the message according to the input you should change in the conditions the **input vars** to itemSelect, just like this:

```
int itemSelect=sales.nextInt();

 if(itemSelect==1){
     System.out.println("You chose Flour");
     int price1=30;
 }
 else if(itemSelect==2){
     System.out.println("You chose Crix");
     int price2=10;
 }
 else if(itemSelect==3){
     System.out.println("You chose Juice");
     int price3=15;
 }
 else if(itemSelect == 4){
     System.out.println("You chose Cereal");
     int price4=25;
 }
```

Comment: Also, i've put int price=20, this allows me to store this date right? Because i need to use these values to do calculations of total cost etc. So is it that when the user selects whichever items, this price would be stored?

Comment: Also am i able to store the price of the items as i have written it in the code. I need these values later on to do calculations.

Comment: Sorry for delay, when you declare a var inside an else if, you will be able to use it later, you have to declare it outside of the condition, maybe below the method signature (local scope, you can use it only inside that method) or below the class signature (global scope, you can use it in the entire class)